# Round edge progress bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, progress-bar

I'm new to android and I'm trying to make a circular progress bar with nice style.

Therefore I found a very simple solution how to make a circular progress bar, using `shape="ring"`

My code is

**mainpage_layout.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="80"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**circular_progress.xml**:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:useLevel="true"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="7dp" >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

and its looks like this

[image]

---

I want to style it like this awesome progress bar :

[image]

**Edit** 
This is the padded background for the progress bar that i want to make

[image]

to add some background to the progress bar and to **make the edges of it be rounded** instead of squared.

Is there is an easy solution to do that or should I must give up on using this `shape="ring"` thing.

Thank you very much,

Asaf.

Comment: Yeah i looked for a library for that but i didnt found something , this is the only one i found https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress , but its not shaped like i mentioned in the second picture, its squared and without background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/korre/android-circular-progress-bar

[image]

There you have a method `useRoundedCorners` you need to pass *false* to make it not round ***by-default it is round*** at the edge

There is a custom class you can actually take from that library(It is more than enough),

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;

public class CircularProgressBar extends View {

    private int mViewWidth;
    private int mViewHeight;

    private final float mStartAngle = -90;      // Always start from top (default is: "3 o'clock on a watch.")
    private float mSweepAngle = 0;              // How long to sweep from mStartAngle
    private float mMaxSweepAngle = 360;         // Max degrees to sweep = full circle
    private int mStrokeWidth = 20;              // Width of outline
    private int mAnimationDuration = 400;       // Animation duration for progress change
    private int mMaxProgress = 100;             // Max progress to use
    private boolean mDrawText = true;           // Set to true if progress text should be drawn
    private boolean mRoundedCorners = true;     // Set to true if rounded corners should be applied to outline ends
    private int mProgressColor = Color.BLACK;   // Outline color
    private int mTextColor = Color.BLACK;       // Progress text color

    private final Paint mPaint;                 // Allocate paint outside onDraw to avoid unnecessary object creation

    public CircularProgressBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircularProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircularProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        initMeasurments();
        drawOutlineArc(canvas);

        if (mDrawText) {
            drawText(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void initMeasurments() {
        mViewWidth = getWidth();
        mViewHeight = getHeight();
    }

    private void drawOutlineArc(Canvas canvas) {

        final int diameter = Math.min(mViewWidth, mViewHeight) - (mStrokeWidth * 2);

        final RectF outerOval = new RectF(mStrokeWidth, mStrokeWidth, diameter, diameter);

        mPaint.setColor(mProgressColor);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(mRoundedCorners ? Paint.Cap.ROUND : Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawArc(outerOval, mStartAngle, mSweepAngle, false, mPaint);
    }

    private void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint.setTextSize(Math.min(mViewWidth, mViewHeight) / 5f);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        mPaint.setColor(mTextColor);

        // Center text
        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((mPaint.descent() + mPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

        canvas.drawText(calcProgressFromSweepAngle(mSweepAngle) + "%", xPos, yPos, mPaint);
    }

    private float calcSweepAngleFromProgress(int progress) {
        return (mMaxSweepAngle / mMaxProgress) * progress;
    }

    private int calcProgressFromSweepAngle(float sweepAngle) {
        return (int) ((sweepAngle * mMaxProgress) / mMaxSweepAngle);
    }

    /**
     * Set progress of the circular progress bar.
     * @param progress progress between 0 and 100.
     */
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mSweepAngle, calcSweepAngleFromProgress(progress));
        animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                mSweepAngle = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        animator.start();
    }

    public void setProgressColor(int color) {
        mProgressColor = color;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setProgressWidth(int width) {
        mStrokeWidth = width;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        mTextColor = color;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void showProgressText(boolean show) {
        mDrawText = show;
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Toggle this if you don't want rounded corners on progress bar.
     * Default is true.
     * @param roundedCorners true if you want rounded corners of false otherwise.
     */
    public void useRoundedCorners(boolean roundedCorners) {
        mRoundedCorners = roundedCorners;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Then you can set the view in your xml like

```
  <yourPackageName.CircularProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/circularProgress"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"/>
```

And in your class you can call it like this,

```
CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularProgress);
circularProgressBar.setProgress(50);
circularProgressBar.setProgressColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Thank you man, i want also to add the padded background. is that possible?

Comment: @asaf regev padded background means mm any example that i can get the idea? you mean two colors from progress bar outline and inline?

Comment: @asaf  study the class i gave (with this example you actually do not need to go and check that lib all what you want is here)and there are useful methods like `drawOutlineArc` you can use em. by-default round edge is true!

Comment: Thank you very much man! the padded backgroud i mean is like in the second picture that i posted- you can see black path for the progress bar, i will edit the post with a new picture @Charu

Comment: @asaf regev you can accept it if answer helps you or post a comment if you need to clear a fact

Comment: please see the picture above in the question description and let me know if you can figure how i can do this background

Comment: @asaf regev yes you need to try that, hint : see there is a method called `calcSweepAngleFromProgress` which accepts your progress if its 100 its fully colored circle right ? you need to have something slimier and set another background color and draw it..Try it its the same way this example use to draw the currant progress and keep that secondary progress as always 100